# Android - highlight text and copy

Tags: android

Is it possible to hilight part of a text and copy in Android?
It's kinda like how in iPhone, when you hold a text for sometime, the box will show up and you can copy then paste that somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

1. Press and hold over input field
2. Select text
3. Drag and highlight the portion of the text you wish to highlight
4. Press and hold over input field again
5. Copy

Comment: Hi Bryan, forgot to mention that I know for links and input field, holding will show the popup. I'm referring to regular text. Is it possible for regular text? Thanks, Tee

Comment: It depends....  In the default web browser you can hit the menu button, more, then Select Text (or Menu + e on hard keyboard).  But this is because the app has it built in, it isn't an OS thing.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the long click as the same of a right click on PC
so usually in android when you press the screen for a while usually a menu will pop out. For texts this menu will contain a text edition tools, like cut, copy and paste

Some apps don't allow the text to be copied but for browsers and general textapps a long click will solve.

So Long click and use the arrows to select the text then press at the top of screen the copy.
To paste just do a long click and at the text box that you want to insert the text and press paste